# ASP.NET Button not redirecting on IE

Tags: jquery, asp.net, vb.net, internet-explorer, button

Currently I have a button which on client click, runs a jquery function that changes the text on a (hidden to the user) label, and then clicks a second (also hidden to the user) button. This second button then runs an ASP.NET function whose last command is to redirect to a second page. The reason I needed to do this, is because I store the value of the label (which is dynamically assigned according to a database) into a session variable BEFORE redirecting to the second page.

This method works perfectly on Chrome and Firefox. Nevertheless, it doesn't seem to be redirecting in IE. It does, however, store the session variable (i.e. the sub routine that handles the hidden button's click event IS called).

Does anyone know why this can be?

Thank you very much for your help! I sincerely appreciate any input.

Edit: I've tried clicking the hidden button myself, and it works fine, so it is definitely something with the postback from the first button interfering with the subroutine called from the second one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why are you redirecting from the ASP.net function? Are you using jQuery AJAX to execute that function? I think your best option is call a jQuery Ajax function which stores your value in session and then (again in your javascript code) do the redirect:

document.location = 'your_new_url.aspx'

Hope that helps.

Try this:

In your javascript code:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "yourPageName.aspx/SetSession",
    data: "{value: '" + the_session_value_you_want_to_store + "'}",
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    dataType: "json",
    success: function (response) {
        if(response.d.length==0) {
            //all was OK, redirect
            document.location = 'your_new_url.aspx';
        } else {
            //mmmm some error
            alert(response.d);
        }
    },
    error: function(msg) {
        alert(msg);
    }
});
```

In your VB.net code:

```
<WebMethod()> _
Public Shared Function SetSession(ByVal value As String) As String
    Dim output As String = String.Empty
    Try
        HttpContext.Current.Session("your_session_variable_name") = value
    Catch ex As Exception
        output = ex.ToString()
    End Try

    Return output
End Function
```

If you can't see the  attribute when writing your server code, add this Imports to your page:
Imports System.Web.Services

Hope that helps.

Comment: Well, I don't know how I would use AJAX to set a session variable :s

Comment: Which server language are you using, C# or VB?

Comment: VB.NET. I didn't even know it was possible to change session variables from jquery. That's amazing.